# I always get errors saying the function is not defined for the jquery plugins I used in meteor 1.3 and React

Tags: meteor, reactjs

In my meteor 1.3 and React apps, when I try to use a jquery plugin, it won't work. On the console, I always see an error saying the function is not defined. For example, `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function`. Earlier I added the js files in the header like this in a index.html file (Placed in the app's root):

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.1.0/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

But since Meteor 1.3 moved all js to the footer, now I load them inside the body tag in the same index file. Now the files are loaded and the jquery plugins can find jQuery without issues. But have trouble using them in the react components. I wrap my functions inside `componentDidMount` and `$(document).ready`. But it's not working. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing it as an npm package? 
As of 1.3 Meteor supports modules and NPM packages: 
http://guide.meteor.com/1.3-migration.html#modules

`meteor npm install --save jquery-countdown`

Package URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-countdown

Then import the dependency where you need it.

Not 100% sure on the import:

`import 'jquery-countdown';`

or something like:

`import {countdown} from 'jquery-countdown'`